# Looping a list of lists, while accessing each elements easily

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I apologise in advance if this has been answered before, I didn't know what to search for.

Say, I want to iterate through a list of lists that looks like this:

```
x = [[a, b, c], [a, b, c], ...]
```

I figured out I can do this to easily access the lists inside that structure:

```
for [a, b, c] in x:
        doSomethingToElements(a,b,c)
```

What I want to do is:

```
for [a, b, c] as wholeList in x:
        doSomethingToElements(a,b,c)
        doSomethingToWholeLists(wholeList)
```

However, that syntax is invalid, is there any equivalent way to do it, which is correct and valid?
Or should I do it with `enumerate()` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)?

EDIT: Working through to make `enumerate()` work, I realise I can do this:

```
for idx, [a, b, c] in enumerate(x):
        doSomethingToElements(a,b,c)
        doSomethingToWholeLists(x[idx])
```

But feel free to post more elegant solutions, or is it elegant enough that it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options.
The first one is iterate element and list together using `zip`, and the second one is iterate the list and assign each value.

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
for (a, b, c), z in zip(x, x):
    print(a, b, c, z)

for z in x:
    a, b, c = z
    print(a, b, c, z)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the zip solution, but yeah the second one is pretty simple i like it

Comment: I feel that this is a good enough solution, that is simple, hence I grant you the accepted answer badge. Also, for any future aspiring developers that encounter this issue but needn't use all three ```a,b,c``` elements, you can use ```_``` for unnecessary ones

Answer (score 1):

There is not really any syntax similar to that suggestion. Your best bet would be [splat-unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
for wholeList in x:
    doSomethingToElements(*wholeList)
    doSomethingToWholeLists(wholeList)
```

Comment: I guess this only works when you pass it through a function right? What if I want to manipulate a,b or c at the spot without a function?

Comment: It works in a few other contexts, e.g. `padded_wholeList = ["pre", *wholeList, "post"]`, but function call syntax is the most common usage.  If you want the local variables within the loop, just assign them: `a, b, c = wholeList`